# Change icon launcher and app name programmatically

Tags: android, android-icons

I saw many posts like this [How to change the icon and label of an app once it is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004230/how-to-change-the-icon-and-label-of-an-app-once-it-is-installed)  but any of those posts could give me the exact answer so as to solve my problem.

I used this but it only changes the action bar icon :

```
 Button appicon1;   
 appicon1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

        });
```

Giving any examples will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 5):

See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15249542/2337837 :
The main idea is to modify your `Activity` section in `AndroidManifest.xml`, then create `<activity-alias>`  for each of your icons, then set enable attribute for the appropriate activity-alias programmatically